# ArrayAdapter doesn't keep it's values

Tags: java, android, collections, android-arrayadapter

I've got a problem, and I know where the problem lays but what I don't understand is why it sometimes works and other times not. This is what I would like to do.

I have an Android application that displays a Google MapView and on top of this MapView there is an autocomplete textview. I get the value from Google (in json-format) and I can display them in this autocomplete textview. This works all of the times. Now when I press on one of the options that I get from Google, I would like to zoom to that location. This works most of the times.

So when I press in the address Elfde, I get 5 options/predictions back from Google. After that I Display those options. One of the options is Elfde-Liniestraat, Belgium. The Google MapView zooms to that location. If I type Bremen, and select Bremen, Germany it zooms to that location. But when I type in Peer and select Peer, Belgium I get a indexOutOfBounds exception in my ArrayAdapter.

Now the code:

When the textchanges in my autocomplete TextView i use this code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (count % 3 == 1){                    
                // Get the places and pass the argument in the TextView to the task.
                GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                task.execute(_txtFindLocation.getText().toString());
            }
        }
```

When I click on an item i use this code:

```
_txtFindLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_txtFindLocation.getWindowToken(), 0);

            Log.v("Take a look on variables", "item: " + String.valueOf(arg2) + ", AdapterView: " + arg0.getCount() + ", _strArrayAdapter: " + _strArrayAdapter.getCount());

            // Move to specified location.
            moveToLocation(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());

                    // Clear the adapter, to decrease the size.
            _strArrayAdapter.clear();
        }
    });
```

And here is where the indexOutOfBoundsException occurs.
For the input and selection of Elfde-Liniestraat, Belgium: arg2 = 0, arg0.getCount() = 5, _strArrayAdapter (that is linked with arg0 as source) = 5
For the input and selection of Bremen, Germany: arg2 = 3, arg0.getCount() = 5, _strArrayAdapter = 5
For the input and selection of Peer, Belgium (where the error is thrown): arg2 = 0, arg0.getCount() = 0, _strArrayAdapter = 0

So defenitely here is where the error is thrown. The _strArrayAdapter gets filled in this function:

```
private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<String> myPredictions = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d("Search places", "params: " + params[0].toString());
        try{
            URL myURL = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8")
                    + "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=API_KEY");
            URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();         
            BufferedReader myBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));

            String strLine;
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            // Take Google's legible JSON and turn it into on big String.
            while((strLine = myBufferReader.readLine()) != null){
                strBuffer.append(strLine);
            }

            // Turn String into a JSON Object.
            JSONObject jsonPredictionsObject = new JSONObject(strBuffer.toString());
            // Get a JSON Array that is inside the JSON Object.
            JSONArray jsonPredictionsArray = new JSONArray(jsonPredictionsObject.getString("predictions"));

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPredictionsArray.length(); i++){
                jsonPredictionsObject = (JSONObject) jsonPredictionsArray.get(i);
                myPredictions.add(jsonPredictionsObject.getString("description"));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Search places", "GetPlaces: doInBackGround", e);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("Search places", "GetPlaces: doInBackGround", e);
        }

        return myPredictions;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
        Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute: " + result.size());

        // Update the adapter.
        _strArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_list_item);
        _strArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        // Attach the adapter to the TextView.
        _txtFindLocation.setAdapter(_strArrayAdapter);

        for (String text : result){
            Log.d("Search places", "onPostExecute: result = " + text);

            _strArrayAdapter.add(text);
        }

            _strArrayAdapter.clear();

        Log.d("Search places", "onPostExecute: autoCompleteAdapter " + _strArrayAdapter.getCount());
    }
```

For all three testcases the last Log.d("Search places", "onPostExecute: autoCompleteAdapter " + _strArrayAdapter.getCount()); give a value of 5!

So the _strArrayAdapter gets filled in all cases, but when I select an Item in some cases the value of the _strArrayAdapter is set to 0, so its not filled.

Why is this happening?

With kind regard,
Martijn Haex

**EDIT** Thanks to the replys, I've revisited my code (above) a little bit and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in following snippet in your `onTextChanged` function. BTW, why are you clearing the array when `lengthOfModifiedText % 3 == 1` ?:

```
if (count % 3 == 1){
                _strArrayAdapter.clear();
```

When you enter `"Peer"`, your array will be cleared (no elements).
Whenever you enter text of length `L, where L % 3 == 1`, your `strArrayAdapter` will be cleared as per your code.

Comment: Ok I get it my _strArrayAdapter gets cleared. But then shouldn't it be cleared for all the testcases? So I don't realy think that this is the problem that I've been looking for. --> why I clear my _strArrayAdapter is because when I type in new letters for my search I don't won't do bee querying Google every time, so when I get 3 new letters than I clear the _strArrayAdapter en query Google. When I queried Google I get 5 predictions and fill the _strArrayAdapter again.

Comment: In all your testcases, the length of text (L) you are entering may not satisfy L % 3 == 1

Comment: Oww you can be correct here, cause when I select one of the predictions that I get from Google. The length of my input in the autocomplete textview it changes. So it will come back in the method onTextChanged. Thank you @Singh, I am going to try and change my code up a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are clearing the results when they have a char count of x*3+1 (1, 4, 7, 10, ...):

```
        if (count % 3 == 1){
            _strArrayAdapter.clear();
```

Seems like you wanted to only search for a place when you hace 3 chars or more, right? That should be

```
        if (count > 3){
            _strArrayAdapter.clear();
```

Also in the postExecute I've found you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() on every item added the the adapter. You could optimize it a bit. Indeed you can remove it altogether:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
    Log.d("YourApp", "onPostExecute: " + result.size());

    // Update the adapter.
    _strArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_list_item);

    for (String text : result){
        Log.d("Search places", "onPostExecute: result = " + text);

        temp.add(text);
        _strArrayAdapter.add(text);
    }


    // Attach the adapter to the TextView.
    _txtFindLocation.setAdapter(_strArrayAdapter);

    Log.d("Search places", "onPostExecute: autoCompleteAdapter " + _strArrayAdapter.getCount());
}
```

Also if you get and exception, put the stacktrace in the post with some refreces to line numbers in the code too so it'll be easier to trace the problem.

Comment: Thanks @rgrocha for the reply, I have put the optimization that you suggested in my code.

Comment: when I use count > 3 than it never seems to query Google, so I let count % 3 = 1 stand a just moved the _strArrayAdapter.clear() to another part of my code --> after I selected a prediciont/option that Google has returned for me.

Comment: ups! sorry, counts doea not means the whole text size, just the new input text size. Replace with if (s.length() > 3) {